# Цикл в языке C++

Tags: c++, циклы

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
// Это программа о том как клео и даффна сделали вклад под проценты
int main()
{
    double kleo = 100;
    double daf = 100;
    double sum = 0;
    //Это для клео
    double prock = 0;
    //Это для даффны
    double procd = 0;
    int k = 0;

    //Тут у клео и даффны сумма вклада растет
    prock = 0.05 * kleo;                        // У клео сумма растет с остатка например у него процент от 100 это 5
    kleo = kleo + prock;                       // а 5 + 100 это 105 а с нее процент это 5,25 и 105 + 5,25 и т.д
    procd = 0.10 * daf;                       // а у даффны сумма вклада растет обычно если у нее 100 вкл. а проц. с этого вкл. 10   
    k += 1;                                  // а 100 + 10 это 110 а при след. проценте будет 120 и т.д
    sum = daf + (procd * k);

    //А это цикл которая у который вклады растут до тех пор пока у клео не будет больше чем у даффны
    for (kleo, daf; kleo >=daf; kleo = kleo + prock)
    {
        prock = 0.05 * kleo;
        procd = 0.10 * daf;
        k += 1;
        sum = daf + (procd * k);
    }

    cout << "Kleo: " << kleo << "\t" << " and daffna: " << sum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Здравствуйте, я написал этот код который про проценты при вкладе и я после того как полностью написал и решаю скомп. и у меня компилятор не компилирует, ну я не мог найти проблему и решил написать сюда, думаю мне помогут и заранее спасибо за помощь =)

Comment: Компилирует, как видите: https://ideone.com/Z0W6R4

Comment: Не понял — за что?!

Comment: Совсем РКН съехал, https://ideone.com/Z0W6R4 недоступен

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы путаете не выполнение программы с  проблемой компиляции. У вас в цикле условие  `kleo >= daf`. Потому что вы добавляете каждый раз `kleo += kleo * 0.05`, а значение `daf` так и не изменяется (вместо этого, у вас растет `sum`). Может вы хотели это:

```
double kleo = 100;
double daf = 100; 
for (int k = 0; kleo >= daf;
    kleo += kleo * 0.05,
    daf += 0.1 * k * daf, ++k);

cout << "Kleo: " << kleo << "\t"
     << " and daffna: " << daf ;
```